# Eclipse: change variable from private to public using refactoring tools (or plugin)?

Tags: java, eclipse, automated-refactoring

There are questions seeking to go from **public to private**. I wish to go the other way.

I have a medium sized project, and I wish to change three commonly used variables from `private` to `public`. The setters and getters are of the form:

```
private int x;
public getX() { return x; }
public setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
```

Is there an easy way to refactor these variables, removing the setters and all references to the setters, and replacing with the variable directly?

As far as I can tell, Eclipse refactoring supports transitioning from public to private, but the other way seems difficult. If it's not supported natively, is there a plugin that can perform this task?

[edit: should add, I'm using Eclipse Kepler, Service Release 2].

Comment: Why do you want a public variable?

Comment: @michael667 The getter and setter add nothing to the class: the values aren't modified by either setter or getter, so all that results is extra bulk in the code that uses these values. It's a very primitive data-type that is used often; I'd prefer consistent access to the variables, and making it public while leaving the setter is just messy.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply keep your getter and setter?

```
public int x;
public getX() { return x; }
public setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
```

Comment: Commented above, but in reply to your answer as well: the getter and setter add nothing to the class: the values aren't modified by either setter or getter, so all that results is extra bulk in the code that uses these values. It's a very primitive data-type that is used often; I'd prefer consistent access to the variables, and making it public while leaving the setter is just messy.

Comment: have you try using the "remplace all" function? or maybe you have an other class using a method with the same name

Comment: Making any member variable public(without good reason) will break encapsulation

Answer (score 0):

There is no such built-in refactoring in Eclipse.  Probably the best you can do is to get Eclipse to locate usages of the methods, and then replace them by hand.  Of course, you can always write your own refactoring within Eclipse, but with the learning curve, that would probably take longer than making the changes by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Although I find this requirement to be very strange (getX() and setX() seem fine by me, even for your use case), you can do this in 3 steps:

1. Change the modifier of field `x` from `private` to `public`
2. Inline the getter `getX()`
3. Inline the setter `setX()`

I tested it locally and it works with Eclipse 3.8.1.